# accessing rows/columns from txt file table in C

Tags: c

I need your help or a little advice with my problem. For example, have a table looking like this:

```
blahbla 4 5 7 44          
lololol 8 7 8 45   
kokooko 1 2 3 4
```

These table has 3 lines and 4 columns, but the number of lines and columns may vary. I need to read values from this table (it is no problem with fopen) but the problem is that i dont know how to access concrete values from this table. For example if I want to printf values only from first line, or only from third column, what am I supposed to do? give me please some advice without using malloc, thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `malloc`?

Comment: I´m not allowed to use it, so I´m looking for another possibility, but i have no idea how to implement this

Comment: you should add the tag "homework-that-i-am-too-lazy-to-do"

Comment: Read the lines and count the spaces.

Comment: I dont want for you to write the code, i want only some advice...

Comment: Don´t avoid malloc, because that makes no sense.

Comment: @deviantfan: To be fair, it *does* make sense if this is destined for an embedded platform with highly restrictive constraints.  Seems unlikely, though.

Answer (score 0):

**Find matrix size**

At first you should find the matrix size. Rows will be easy, you only have to count number of lines (I'm assuming that you are reading data from .txt file). Next thing is columns. If all rows will have the same number of elements, you can iterate over the string that is the first line and check if elements of the string are letters (for example with isalpha function). If element is a letter, then you can increment the number of columns - if not, then it will be space or number, if it is a space then you should increment number of columns variable, and if it is not then you have to skip to the next element.
If the number of elements in rows of your table may vary, then you should iterate over every line and find the number of columns like in previous case, finding the maximum.

**Create matrix and copy data**

Now, when you have size of your matrix you can allocate it like this: string table[numberOfRows][numberOfColumns] - then you should once again iterate over the data in txt file, checking if the element in line is alpha or is space. If it is a space and the next character is numeric(you can check it with isdigit and isspace), then you should make some string variable that you will be concatenating until it hits another space or end of line - then you assign it to matrix. If it is letter then it will be easy, just assign it to proper place in the matrix. Remeber that you will have to fill additional elements in the matrix with something like "0" (of course only if the rows can have different number of elements).

**Retrieve data**

You can retrieve data only from column or a row, simply create an array that has size of your table columns or rows, then you can for example iterate over your table and check if the row(column) is the one that is interesting you. And if it is, assign it to your array. Then you can print it with another loop.